# Yii update cgridview via ajax button not working.

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have in my controller:

```
public function actionFilterClients {
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        if (isset($_POST['category_id'])) {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition = "user_id=:user_id";
            $criteria->params = array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id);
            $criteria->compare('category_id',$_POST['category_id'],true);

            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Client', array(
                                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                                ));
            $this->renderPartial('transfer_step_3' , array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider)) ;
        }
    }
}
```

In my view among other things I have:

```
<?php $filter=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'client-filter-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal'),
        )); ?>
        <label for="category_id">View clients in category:</label>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id','',Client::clientCategories(), array('options' => array('2'=>array('selected'=>true)))); ?>

        <?php
            echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
                'Filter Clients',
                'filterclients',
                array(
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'update'  => 'client-grid' ,
                    'success' =>"function(data) {
         \$.fn.yiiGridView.update('client-grid');}",
                )
            );
        ?>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
            'type'=>'bordered striped condensed',
            'id'=>'client-grid',
            'ajaxUpdate' => true ,
            'rowCssClassExpression'=>'($data->duplicate==2)?"yellow":($data->duplicate==1?"blue":"")',
            'dataProvider'=>(isset($dataProvider)?$dataProvider:$clients->moveclients()),
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
            'columns'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
                    'selectableRows'=>2,
                    'id'=>'clients',
                ),
                'name',
                'surname',
                'telephone',
                'email',
                array(
                    'header'=>'Category',
                    'name' => 'category_title',
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->category->title',
                ),
            ),
        )); ?>
```

Because this is a multi-step form, the cgridview dataprovider defaults to listing all clients ($clients->moveclients() lists all clients).

The ajax button posts the `category_id` to the client/filterclients url correctly.

I can see with firebug that actionFilterClients returns the rendered html correctly (with the correct clients) but the gridview is not updated...

Any ideas on why not?

Comment: please remove this line from your code and see what hapens? 'success' =>"function(data) {
         $.fn.yiiGridView.update('client-grid');}"

Comment: Now filterclients is called correctly but the POST response in firebug is blank

Comment: ok, looks like isset($_POST) is returning false so its not going inside if code. Please write these line CVarDumper::Dump($_POST,100,true);die() right after where you are checking isAjaxRequest

Comment: then look the response you get in firebug and let me know

Comment: POST filterusers response was: `array
(
    'category_id' => '3'
)`

Comment: hmm, that means $_POST['category_id'] is not empty so it is entering in if statement. strange, it should return content-type:html/text

Comment: It is entering the if statement, both of them, it is finding the proper filtered users and I can see from Firebug that the content type is text/html. The html returned is what it should be from renderPartial i.e. the two forms (drop-down & gridview) with the proper users displayed in the gridview.
For some reason though the whole view is not being updated...

Comment: ok then the last possibility is that please check the id of cgridView in rendered page because i think its being not set to 'client-grid'

Comment: try 'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'client-grid') in your TbGridView and then try ajax call

Comment: Sorry, no go!
What I did notice though is that two requests are being made, one POST to filterclients that returns as I said properly, and one GET to client/transfer?ajax=client-grid (client/transfer is the current route).
Because the form as I said is multi-step the html returned from this call is from a previous view.
I don't know how that would make a difference though..

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added another view that had only a gridview in it and modified my code thus:

Controller:

```
$this->renderPartial('_ajax_transfer_step_3' , array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider)) ;
```

Original view:

```
<?php $filter=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'customer-filter-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal'),
        )); ?>
        <label for="category_id">View customers in category:</label>
        <?php

            echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id', '', Customer::customerCategories(),
                array(
                        'ajax' => array(
                                'type'=>'POST',
                                'url'=>CController::createUrl('filtercustomers'),
                                'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).serialize()',
                                'success'=>'function(response) {
                                        jQuery("#customer-grid").html(response)

                                }',
                        )
                )
            );
        ?>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Now it just replaces a portion of the page.

I still haven't figured out why my original code didn't update the gridview though.